# iOS navigation controller without navigation bar

Tags: ios

This is how I launched by main controller in my iOS app.

```
UIViewController *rootController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

With this I am getting a blank bar at the top.

[image]

I want to use a navigation controller to control the flow of screens that users are able to reach by pressing back but I don't want a navigation bar. How can I change my code to get what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code right after you declare `navigationController = ...` in the code sample you provided:

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:true];
```

And then whenever you need to go "back," your app would run this code from within the current view controller:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
```